# ActiveMQ persistence: some troubles with AMQ Message Store

Tags: java, spring, activemq-classic

I'm continuing to learn ActiveMQ, and have some question:
I've read a lot ActiveMQ persistence references and docs, and noticed one thing - default message store (as I understand) is AMQ Message Store, that can be configured by such XML code snippet:

```
<broker ...>    
   ....
   <persistenceAdapter>
      <amqPersistenceAdapter directory="activemq-data/store" maxFileLength="10mb"/>
   </persistenceAdapter>
   ....
</broker>
```

But I'm confused a little - when I looks through xml schema (http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd) there is no element amqPersistenceAdapter. Don't I understand something?
So it's an obvious that when I'm running my app an Exception occurs:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 44 in XML document from class path resource [config.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 44; columnNumber: 86; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'amq:amqPersistenceAdapter'. One of '{"http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":jdbcPersistenceAdapter, "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":journalPersistenceAdapter, "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":kahaDB, "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":levelDB, "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":mKahaDB, "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":memoryPersistenceAdapter, "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":replicatedLevelDB, WC[##other:"http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"]}' is expected.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:252)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:452)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.jmsexamples.Main.main(Main.java:7)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 44; columnNumber: 86; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'amq:amqPersistenceAdapter'. One of '{"http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":jdbcPersistenceAdapter, "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":journalPersistenceAdapter, "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":kahaDB, "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":levelDB, "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":mKahaDB, "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":memoryPersistenceAdapter, "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":replicatedLevelDB, WC[##other:"http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"]}' is expected.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:325)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:458)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3237)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1796)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.emptyElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:766)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:356)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2786)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:347)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:429)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
    ... 14 more
```

here is Spring config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd        
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-3.0.xsd
        http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core 
        http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd
    " >


    <bean 
            id="producer"
            class="com.jmsexamples.Producer">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsFactory" />  
    </bean>

    <bean 
            id="consumer"
            class="com.jmsexamples.Consumer"> 
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsFactory" />      
    </bean>

    <bean id="jdbc_ds" 
                class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
                destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ActiveMq?relaxAutoCommit=true" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
        <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <amq:connectionFactory id="jmsFactory" brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616"/>

    <amq:queue id="queue" physicalName="message.queue" />

    <amq:broker id="msgBroker" persistent="true">
    <amq:persistenceAdapter>
       <amq:amqPersistenceAdapter directory="activemq-data/store" maxFileLength="10mb"/>
    </amq:persistenceAdapter>

    <amq:transportConnectors>
      <amq:transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://localhost:61616" />
    </amq:transportConnectors> 

  </amq:broker>
</beans>
```

Comment: do not use amqPersistenceAdapter as that is the old data store, but use kahadb which is the current recommended - http://activemq.apache.org/persistence.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ActiveMQ uses the KahaDB persistence adapter by default these days, the old amq adapter is deprecated and not support in new versions.  You can configure various aspects of KahaDB in the XML the basic element looks as follows:

```
  <broker brokerName="broker" ... >
     <persistenceAdapter>
       <kahaDB directory="activemq-data" journalMaxFileLength="32mb"/>
       </persistenceAdapter>
  </broker>
```

Refer to the [KahaDB page](http://activemq.apache.org/kahadb.html) for more info:

Comment: Thank you a much! I'm wondered that I hadn't found any information that amqPersistenceAdapter is deprecated.